# TweenLite vs Jquery animate

Tags: jquery, gsap

I have some simple animation to change the height of a div up and down on click. 
I usually use jquery slide or animate. This time I looked into TweenLite to see how it worked.
The issue I'm having is adding more file size. Ok TweenLite is only 9kb no big deal but if you want to animate the css properties then you have to also load the CSSPlugin for TweenLite. Now this is much larger 25kb which to me is a big deal for a tiny page project.

From what I have read jquery is animating the object and not its css properties or am I wrong. 
Is the only gain for TweenLite + CSSEngine is that it's animating the css so it's faster?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery animates the css too. If all you're doing is animating the height of an object (or just a few), and you're already locked into using jQuery elsewhere, then jQuery should be fine for those animations. However, if you're doing anything more aggressive or you're running into performance problems or need more control over the animations, I'd definitely recommend switching to TweenLite + CSSPlugin.

The reason TweenLite is so much faster has to do with its internal infrastructure and a bunch of optimizations - it's not because it's animating different properties altogether. It's just a lot more efficient.

The reason CSSPlugin is that size is because it allows you to do so much, **FAR** more than jQuery can. Like 2D and 3D transforms, borderRadius, textShadow, clip, colors, and lots more. And it works around a slew of browser bugs. See http://www.greensock.com/why-gsap/ for a summary, and http://www.greensock.com/jquery/ for a head-to-head comparison with jQuery.

If file size is your primary concern, TweenLite + CSSPlugin is a lot less than jQuery alone, but again if you're locked into using jQuery elsewhere then you'll have to decide if GSAP is worth the file size in your particular project. Frankly, it's really not very heavy, all things considered. It's like the size of an image, so it might be worth that price if it gets you better runtime performance. Again, it all depends on your particular project. A few simple height tweens probably don't need GSAP.